# Como dar quebra de linha na geração de arquivo txt para impressão?

Tags: php, html, txt

Tenho um formulário de pedidos, e preciso que seja quebrado a linha a cada novo produto, um item por linha, mas não esta funcionando:

```
<input name="cpf" type="hidden" value="<?=$ec2[cpf];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="prds" class="form-control" value="
<?php
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from dl_carrinho where ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'");
while($pg = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $pg[produto]."<br>";
}
?>" />

<textarea style="display:none;" name="cp_produtos">
<?php
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from dl_carrinho where ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'"); $i = 0;
while($pg = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
$i++;
echo "$i-$pg[produto]R$".number_format($pg[preco],2,",",".")."\r";
}
?>
</textarea>


                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php
if($_POST[fnpedido]) {
    $qrdan = $qr + $_POST[bar];

if($_POST[pagamento] == "Dinheiro") {
$qrws = "Dinheiro, troco para <b>R$ " . $_POST[pagamento2] . "</b>";
$cp_pc1 = "DINHEIRO";
$n0w = $_POST[pagamento2] - $qrdan;
$cp_pc2 = "LEVAR R$ ".number_format($n0w,2,",",".")." DE TROCO";
$cp_valor = $_POST[pagamento2];
}
if($_POST[pagamento] == "Cartão de Crédito") {
$qrws = "Cart&atilde;o de Cr&eacute;dito";
$cp_pc1 = "CARTAO DE CREDITO/DÉBITO";
$cp_pc2 = "LEVAR MAQUINA PARA CARTAO";
$cp_valor = $qrdan;
}
if($_POST[pagamento] == "PayPal") {
$cp_pc1 = "PAYPAL";
$cp_pc2 = "ANALISAR PAGAMENTO NO PAYPAL";
$cp_valor = $qrdan;
}

if($_SESSION[cupom_nome]) {
    $cprom = "Cupom: $_SESSION[cupom_nome] -$_SESSION[cupom_desc]%";
}

if(!file_exists('entrega')) {
echo '<br><div class="alert alert-info fade in"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:0.5%;"></span> Desculpe, n&atilde;o estamos entregando no momento. </div>';

} elseif($cfg[minimo] > $qrdan) {
echo '<br><div class="alert alert-info fade in"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:0.5%;"></span> Desculpe, o valor min&iacute;mo para entregas &eacute; de R$ '.$cfg[minimo].'. </div>';
} else {
$ps = $mysqli->query("select * from dl_pedidos order by id desc");
$new_d = $ps->fetch_assoc();
$new_dd = $new_d[id] + 1;
$hrio = date('Y-m-d');
$hrio2 = date('H')."h".date('i');
$tend = "".post(endereco)." [Complemento: ".post(nm)."]";
$mysqli->query("insert into dl_pedidos(valor,data,hora,descricao,email,produtos,end) values('".$qrdan."','".$hrio."','".$hrio2."','
                                    <thead>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Dados</th>
<th>Produtos</th>
<th>Local de entrega</th>
<th>Observações</th>
<th>Pagamento de R$ ".number_format($qrdan,2,",",".")."</th>
   </thead>

<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td>".$new_dd."</td>
    <td>".post(nome)."<br>".post(tel)."</td>
    <td>".$_POST[prds]."</td>
    <td>".post(endereco)."<br>".post(cep)."<br>Complemento: ".post(nm)."</td>
    <td>".post(descricao)."</td>
    <td>".$qrws." em ".data()." ".$cprom."</td>
  </tbody>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
','".$_SESSION[l0g1n]."','".$_POST[prds]."','".$tend."')");

logs("Realizou o pedido #".$new_dd.".");
if(empty($cfg[tel2])) { $cp_tel = $cfg[tel1]; } else { $cp_tel = $cfg[tel1]."/".$cfg[tel2]; }
$cp_ped = sprintf('%010d', $new_dd);
$cp_data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$cp_valor = number_format($qrdan,2,",",".");
$cp_produtos = post(cp_produtos);
if(empty($_SESSION[cupom_desc])) { $cp_ccp = 0; } else { $cp_ccp = $_SESSION[cupom_desc]; }
if(empty($_POST[descricao])) { $cp_desc = "NENHUMA"; } else { $cp_desc = $_POST[descricao]; }

$abr1 = fopen("comprovantes/".$new_dd.".txt","w+");
fwrite($abr1, mb_strtoupper("EMPRESA: $cfg[empresa]
END.:$cfg[endereco]
END.: $cfg[endereco2]
TEL.: $cp_tel
-----------------------------------------
P E D I D O        DATA EMISSAO         
$cp_ped         $cp_data
ATENDENTE: DELIVERY MODELO
-----------------------------------------
             E N T R E G A                    
CLIENTE: $_POST[nome]
ENDERECO: $_POST[endereco] - $_POST[nm]
TELEFONE: $_POST[tel]
CEP: $_POST[cep]
-----------------------------------------
ITEM   /   DESCRICAO   /   VALOR UNITARIO
-----------------------------------------
**************[ PRODUTOS ]***************
$cp_produtos
-----------------------------------------
         TOTALIZACAO DO PEDIDO     
TOTAL A PAGAR: R$ $cp_valor
DESCONTO DO CUPOM: $cp_ccp%
-----------------------------------------
PAGAMENTO: $cp_pc1
>>>>>>> $cp_pc2 <<<<<<<
-----------------------------------------
OBS.: $cp_desc
-----------------------------------------

   ESTE CUPOM NAO TEM VALIDADE FISCAL  

-----------------------------------------
",'UTF-8'));
fclose($abr1);
```

O resultado na geração e impressão txt é a seguinte...

```
EMPRESA: DELIVERY (MODELO)
END.: RUA MODELO, 123
END.: RUA MODELO, 123
TEL.: 1111111111
-----------------------------------------
P E D I D O DATA EMISSAO
0000000042 18/05/2019 10:16:46
ATENDENTE: DELIVERY MODELO
-----------------------------------------
 E N T R E G A
CLIENTE: TESTE
ENDERECO: RUA TESTE, 1000 - CASA
TELEFONE: 1111111111
CEP: 11111111
-----------------------------------------
ITEM / DESCRICAO / VALOR UNITARIO
-----------------------------------------
**************[ PRODUTOS ]***************
1- COCA COLA 2L R$9,00\R\N2- COCA COLA 2L R$9,00\R\N
-----------------------------------------
 TOTALIZACAO DO PEDIDO
TOTAL A PAGAR: R$ 21,00
DESCONTO DO CUPOM: 0%
-----------------------------------------
PAGAMENTO: CARTAO DE CREDITO/DÉBITO
>>>>>>> LEVAR MAQUINA PARA CARTAO <<<<<<<
-----------------------------------------
OBS.: NENHUMA
-----------------------------------------

 ESTE CUPOM NAO TEM VALIDADE FISCAL
```

No campo abaixo é que preciso resolver a separação dos produtos por linha!!!

```
 **************[ PRODUTOS ]***************

1- COCA COLA 2L R$9,00\R\N2- COCA COLA 2L R$9,00\R\N

******************************************
```

Comment: O correto para pular linha não seria `\n` ?

Comment: Tenta colocar um <br>

Answer (score 0):

Na impressão em um arquivo, é necessário utilizar o comando **`\n`**.

Para impressão que é interpretado no navegador, utiliza-se o **`<br>`**.

Answer (score 0):

```css
Tudo que coloco no TEXTAREA para quebrar linha como:

- \N ele aparece 1- COCA COLA 2L R$9,00  \R\N2  - COCA COLA 2L R$9,00  \R\N

- se coloco <br> aparece 1- COCA COLA 2L R$9,00  <br>  - COCA COLA 2L R$9,00  <br>

*Acredito que possa ter algum código que faça a quebra no TEXTAREA e não apareça o mesmo.
```